# Issue with the conditions in a for loop

Tags: perl

I have two files represented by `$outputfile6` and `$outputfile7` in my script. Both files have the same contents (all the fields are same) and a total of 10 fields in this scenario. Although both the files are the same I am not getting any contents in the file : `$outputfile2` . Below is the code.

```
open my $outputfile2, ">", "hung_jobs.txt"              or die $!;

open my $outputfile6, "<", "active_jobs_all_fields.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile7, "<", "hung_jobs_old.txt"          or die $!;

my @arr  = <$outputfile6>;
my @arr1 = <$outputfile7>;

foreach my $line2 (@arr) {
   chomp $line2;
   my @split = split( ' ', $line2 );

   foreach my $line3 (@arr1) {
      chomp $line3;
      my @split1 = split( ' ', $line3 );

      if ( $split[9] == $split1[9] ) {
         print $outputfile2 "Hello";
         print $outputfile2 "$split[0] $split[3] $split[5] $split[6] \n";
      }

      print $outputfile5 $outputfile2;
   }
}
```

Comment: foreach line in ouputfile6 you are reading eachline in outputfile7.. is this right? so if out6 have 10 lines and out7 has 10 lines you get 100 compares

Comment: yes lordkain correct

Comment: can you print  $split[9] and $split1[9]  to see if you ha a mach somewhere/... before the if check

Comment: So you have variables named `outputfiles` for files you are reading from?

Comment: Are you sure the two files are exactly identical? What does `diff active_jobs_all_fields.txt hung_jobs_old.txt` say?

Comment: yes jcaron this is true. Please help I am very new to Perl.

Comment: Does the 10th column actually contain only numbers?

Comment: Perl or no perl, if they're input files, call them input files, not output files!

Comment: Are fields actually separated by spaces in both files?

Comment: Have you printed the number of row in each of `@arr` and `@arr1` — or, equivalently, have you checked that the files are non-empty?  What is the last `print` meant to be doing?  You don't show `$outputfile5` being opened.  Have you printed the `$split[9]` and `$split1[9]` values before you compare them?  Are they what you expect?  Are they numeric columns?  (Perl's `==` is for numbers; `eq` is for strings.  This probably isn't the issue.)

Comment: The files are same                                                                             [ec2-user@testing]$ diff hung_jobs_old.txt active_jobs_all_fields.txt
[ec2-user@testing]$ ls -lrt hung_jobs_old.txt active_jobs_all_fields.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1267 Dec  9 10:41 hung_jobs_old.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1267 Dec  9 10:41 active_jobs_all_fields.txt

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with `print $outputfile5 $outputfile2;` This would print the file handle `$outputfile2` to `$outputfile5`

Comment: The delimiter is space in both the files. yes 10th column is a number

Comment: There's also no `$outputfile5` defined.

Comment: You should show us sample data — say 5 lines from each file, where some of those lines should be paired and some should not.

Comment: The script is big . Apologies I forgot to mention that $outputfile5 is already defined.  open my $outputfile5, ">", "hung_jobs_old.txt" or die $!;

Comment: OMG! The lines from handle `$outputfile7` are placed in `@arr1`, and then in `$line3`. What's with the inconsistencies in the numbers?!?!?!

Comment: `open my $outputfile5, ">", "hung_jobs_old.txt" or die $!;`? So you're truncating hung_jobs_old.txt while trying to read from it?

Comment: [ec2-user@testing]$ cat hung_jobs_old.txt | awk '{print $10}'
66431488
100677632
128579072
130149376
201490176
141490688
160213504
163885312
168801536
151044608
121175552
688414976
561467392
[ec2-user@testing]$ cat active_jobs_all_fields.txt | awk '{print $10}'
66431488
100677632
128579072
130149376
201490176
141490688
160213504
163885312
168801536
151044608
121175552
688414976
561467392
[ec2-user@testing]$

Comment: @ikegami This is my second day of learning PERL. Please forgive me in case i made  silly mistakes

Comment: Make sure your script has `use warnings 'all'; use strict;`, and let us know of any warnings or errors it produces.

Comment: The language's name is "Perl", and that mistake had nothing to do with Perl.

Comment: Since you are new to [so] in addition to Perl, please take a moment to [tour] the site, learn about how to create a [mcve], and learn about [ask] a good question.

Comment: Sure Matt. I will go through the site.

Comment: @RahulM: Please state your question in the title! It is not clear what the problem is. This makes this question useless to other SO visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what the problem is.  When I take your script and add some diagnostic printing, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$, = " ";
open my $outputfile2, ">", "hung_jobs.txt"              or die $!;
open my $outputfile6, "<", "active_jobs_all_fields.txt" or die $!;
open my $outputfile7, "<", "hung_jobs_old.txt"          or die $!;
my @arr  = <$outputfile6>;
my @arr1 = <$outputfile7>;
print "arr = ", scalar(@arr), ", arr1 = ", scalar(@arr1), "\n";
foreach my $line2 (@arr) {
   chomp $line2;
   my @split = split( ' ', $line2 );
   print "S0:", @split;
   foreach my $line3 (@arr1) {
      chomp $line3;
      my @split1 = split( ' ', $line3 );
      print "S1:", @split1;
      if ( $split[9] == $split1[9] ) {
         print $outputfile2 "Hello";
         print $outputfile2 "$split[0] $split[3] $split[5] $split[6] \n";
         print "$split[0] $split[3] $split[5] $split[6]\n";
      }
      #print $outputfile5 $outputfile2;
   }
}
```

and when I create the two data files:

```
$ cat active_jobs_all_fields.txt
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 10
$ cat hung_jobs_old.txt
g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 10
$
```

then when I run it, I get to see:

```
$ perl -l x37.pl
arr =  1 , arr1 =  1 

S0: f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 10
S1: g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 10
f1 f4 f6 f7

$ cat hung_jobs.txt
Hello
f1 f4 f6 f7 

$
```

This seems to correspond to what you want.  So it is not clear what your problem is.

The stray blank lines can be attributed to the `-l` option.  Tested with Perl 5.22.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.2 (built on an earlier version).

Comment: Hello Jonathan. When I ran your script , I got the desired data in the Output file : hung_jobs.txt. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please help me identify the problem which was there in the script previously.

Comment: No — because I can't work out what you are doing wrong. I added the shebang and `use` lines; set `$, = " ";` so the array printing is spaced. I added the print statements in the loops; I added a print statement to standard output when the `if` is taken. I didn't try writing to `$outputfile5`. The `-l` option isn't crucial; it makes the output better formatted (your outputs don't include newlines). Otherwise, the code is verbatim what you wrote. Only the strictest reading of the commented out `print` line prevents the code you posted from running as is. I think you need to look at your files.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide enough to demonstrate your problem, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

But I'd like to point out the approach is awful. If you have 1,000 lines in both files, you'll end up executing the loop body 1,000,000 times. In that same scenario, the following only executes each loop body 1000 times:

```
my %active_jobs;
{
   open(my $fh, "<", "active_jobs_all_fields.txt")
      or die $!;

   while (<$fh>) {
      my @fields = split;
      $active_jobs{$fields[9]} = "$fields[0] $fields[3] $fields[5] $fields[6]\n";
   }
}

{
   open(my $in_fh, "<", "hung_jobs_old.txt")
      or die $!;
   open(my $out_fh, ">", "hung_jobs.txt")
      or die $!;

   while (<$in_fh>) {
      my $key = (split)[9];
      print($out_fh $active_jobs{$key}) if $active_jobs{$key};
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ikegami. I will keep this thing in mind going forward. I will try this version as well.